# Cannot override theme_links() in fusion subtheme

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-themes

I have setup a subtheme under Fusion and created a template.php file in my subtheme. I have added the following theme overrides and it works perfectly.

```
function ThemeName_menu_local_tasks() {
    $output = '';
  if ($primary = menu_primary_local_tasks()) {
    $output .= "<div class=\"tabs primary\">\n";
    $output .= "<ul class=\"tabs primary\">\n" . $primary . "</ul>\n";
    $output .= "</div>\n";
  }
  if ($secondary = menu_secondary_local_tasks()) {
    $output .= "<div class=\"tabs secondary\">\n";
    $output .= "<ul class=\"tabs secondary\">\n" . $secondary . "</ul>\n";
    $output .= "</div>\n";    
  }
  return $output;
}

function ThemeName_filter_tips_more_info () {
    return '';
}

function ThemeName_filter_tips() {
    return '';
}
```

However, when I try to override theme_links, it doesn't work at all.

```
function ThemeName_links($links, $attributes = array('class' => 'links')) {
  global $language;
  $output = '';

  if (count($links) > 0) {
    $output = '<div class = "abc"><ul' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>';

    $num_links = count($links);
    $i = 1;

    foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
      $class = $key;

      // Add first, last and active classes to the list of links to help out themers.
      if ($i == 1) {
        $class .= ' first';
      }
      if ($i == $num_links) {
        $class .= ' last';
      }
      if (isset($link['href']) && ($link['href'] == $_GET['q'] || ($link['href'] == '<front>' && drupal_is_front_page()))
           && (empty($link['language']) || $link['language']->language == $language->language)) {
        $class .= ' active';
      }
      $output .= '<li' . drupal_attributes(array('class' => $class)) . '>';

      if (isset($link['href'])) {
        // Pass in $link as $options, they share the same keys.
        $output .= l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link);
      }
      else if (!empty($link['title'])) {
        // Some links are actually not links, but we wrap these in <span> for adding title and class attributes
        if (empty($link['html'])) {
          $link['title'] = check_plain($link['title']);
        }
        $span_attributes = '';
        if (isset($link['attributes'])) {
          $span_attributes = drupal_attributes($link['attributes']);
        }
        $output .= '<span' . $span_attributes . '>' . $link['title'] . '</span>';
      }

      $i++;
      $output .= "</li>\n";
    }

    $output .= '</ul></div>';
  }

  return $output;
}
```

By the way, I added the following to ThemeName_links() above for testing.

```
<div class = "abc"> and </div>
```

I have also cleared Flush all cache using Devel.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you do is correct (I am referring to the way you do theme override) and Fusion theme system also works well. At first, when I try to use Fusion theme, I face the same issue as you. But after I went through the Fusion system, and see how Fusion shows the links (include primary-links, secondary-links), I discovered that inside **fusion/fusion_core/page.tpl.php** file they call this function **theme('grid_block', $primary_links_tree, 'primary-menu')** to show the primary-links. This is the function theme written by Fusion. So what you need to do is simple, You can call the default theme links function of Drupal: **theme('links', $primary_links)** and override your ThemName_links() from there on.

One more thing I'm trying to do now is **to override grid_block function**. If I find out something interesting, I will post more later.